# Compare elements in a array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing an angular application and here I want to compare product quantities contains in the following prductpath array. As an example, I want to compare `array[0].qty` with `array[1].qty` and `array[1].qty` with `array[2].qty`. Array length should not be exceeded.

```
 [

  0:{qty:120}

  1:{qty:110}

  2:{qty:130}

]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How do you want to compare the `qty`s? by equality, inequalities, etc...? Once you've compared all values what do you want to be returned?

Comment: Here I used [ngClass] and dynamically colour some table rows if there is an inequality between those quantities. In my use case, these quantities should be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop to compare the object's property one by one.

The following example shows how to find the largest `qty`:

```js
var elArr = [{qty:120},{qty:110},{qty:130}];
var largestQty = elArr[0].qty;
for(let i = 1; i<elArr.length; i++){
  if(elArr[i].qty > largestQty)
    largestQty = elArr[i].qty;
}
console.log(largestQty);
```